# Ruby IRC in parallel with Rubygame

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I use Cinch library for an IRC bot and Rubygame to display state of the game to the user.

I want some users to be able to update the screen sending an IRC command. That's to say, if I use `!addpoints`, the points shown on the screen would be updated. I have no problem handling both parts without considering the other one and I can run one from another because they are singletons.

That's to say, at any time, I can use `Screen::add_points` or `IRC::send_confirm_message`.

The only problem is that when I run Rubygame, it does a loop to wait for events and never starts Cinch and that's the same the other way round.

Is there a way to make the two work in the same time and communicate ? Like some sort of thread ?